# How do I set a default FileHandle attribute with moose

Tags: perl, moose, filehandle

You may infer from the question that this is my first Moose class.

How do I set an attribute `FileHandle` to `*STDOUT`?

This doesn't work.

```
has 'output' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'FileHandle',
    default => sub { openhandle(*STDOUT) }
);
```

The output when run is:

```
Attribute (output) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'FileHandle' with value *main::STDOUT
```

The documentation claims:

> FileHandle accepts either an IO::Handle object or a builtin perl
>   filehandle (see "openhandle" in Scalar::Util).

What am I missing?

Thanks.

-E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what else you may need there, but this works for starters

The **WithFH.pm**

```
package WithFH;

use feature 'say';
use Moose;

has 'fh' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'FileHandle', default => sub { \*STDOUT } );

sub say {
    my $self = shift;
    say { $self->{fh} } "@_";
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;    
1;
```

and the main

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use WithFH;

my $wfh = WithFH->new;

$wfh->say("hi");
```

That prints `hi` to `STDOUT`.

Comment: Works like a champ.  Thanks.

Comment: Using `{openhandle(\*STDOUT)}` works, too.  Though I don't know why I'd need it, now.

Comment: @ErikBennett Welcome :) Note: We normally don't have to use the proper typeglob _reference_, `\*STDOUT` (even when it's strictly speaking needed),  and can use simply `*STDOUT` (or even `STDOUT`); however, Moose won't allow it here.

Comment: @ErikBennett Yeah ... I am not certain why they mention `openhandle` in docs.  I suppose it's because it checks whether the thing can be a filehandle. But then, this is not passed in dynamically and hopefully one knows what they are doing with defaults so I don't see much value in that check.  Also, for the default I may want a filehandle which specifically _isn't_ open, like `default => sub { FileHandle->new }`; the `openhandle` will return `undef` if the thing isn't open.

Comment: @ErikBennett Altogether, `openhandle(\*STDOUT)` checks your stream. Why not; `STDOUT` _could_ get unavailable.